# Laravel collection to javascript json then search for value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, laravel

I'm using laravel to create a collection of users who can have multiple items. I want to pass that collection to a javascript object, so that I can check if a user has a particular object.

I use the following line to get the content of the collection and pass it to the page :

`let items = {!! $user->items->toJson() !!};`

this is giving me the following structure :

`Array ->
0: Object {brand: "brand1", reference: "23423", description: "Item 1 description text"}
1: Object {brand: "brand2", reference: "22344", description: "Item 6 description text"}
2: Object {brand: "brand1", reference: "23239", description: "Item 24 description text"}
3: Object {brand: "brand5", reference: "24908", description: "Item 106 description text"}
4: Object {brand: "brand3", reference: "14545", description: "Item 7 description text"}`

How can I check if reference "14545" (for instance) is part of the array ?

thanks for your help.

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using find function here is an example

```
const data = [20, 18, 15, 10, 9];

let found = data.find(element => element < 12);

console.log(found);
```

for you it's going to be something like

```
let found = data.find(element => element.reference == "22235");
```

if found is null that's mean there's no ref equal to "22235"

wish it helped you

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ES6**  `find()` method to search `JSON` for specific element

```
let result = items.find(el => el.reference == "14545");
```

**OR**

You can use below function for the same:

```
var getObjectByValue = function (array, key, value) {
    return array.filter(function (object) {
        return object[key] === value;
    });
};
```

Example:

```
getObjectByValue(items, "reference", "14545" );
```